# Track Logs of installed apk in android

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, logging, apk

Im new to android development. I want to track logs in the testing devices, i googled it and i'm confused pls guide which is the correct way.
1. Can Log4j be used and save the logs in device sd card?
2. Firebase Analytics can be used? Is that free to use or paid?
3. Or any other tracking solution?

Guide me which is the correct way to track the logs. Since my app is based on notifications it behaves abnormal randomly in different versions and im not able to track the log

Comment: you can use logcat from android studio

Comment: i use logcat in android studio now when device is connected to my computer i can track the logs. Can logcat be used to track if mobile is not connected to machine which installed unsigned apk for testing? If yes pls guide me with example

Answer (score 2):

For that, you can use [Logcat Extreame](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=scd.lcex) app. You can view per-app logs in it.

setup:

if your device is rooted you don't need to do anything special to get logs.
For unrooted devices, grant read_logs permission by following these

> steps:
>   1) install ADB (Android Debug Bridge) on your computer
>   2) connect your Android device to the computer
>   3) open shell (Linux,Mac) or command prompt (Windows) and run the following command "adb
>   shell pm grant scd.lcex android.permission.READ_LOGS"

Logcat Extreme is free and even free of ads

Comment: Is firebase analytics free for Developer environment?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command:

```
adb shell logcat YOURLOGTAG:I *:S
```

you can use Log from android.util, example `Log.i (YOURTAG, "Hello")`